# What is the current status of ${\cal N}=8$ Supergravity among physicists?

Tags: supergravity

On April 24 2018, Z. Bern et al wrote this https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09311

A conclusion of this paper is that the 5-loop four-point amplitude of ${\cal N}=8$ supergravity first diverges at $D = 24/5$.

Based on the trend given by https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702112 and https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2326, it seems like in four dimensions ${\cal N}=8$ supergravity is finite. In your circles, is there a dramatic change in interest in supergravity, or is string theory still dominant?